# Как вывести с помощью Python Pillow эмодзи на фото?

Tags: python, pillow

Если добавить эмодзи в текст, то оно отображается как белый смайлик, а не полноценное эмодзи.

Вот часть кода:

```
drawer.text((65, 56), f"{hour}:{minute}", (255,255,255), font=font)
font = ImageFont.truetype("C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Semibold.otf", 49)
```

Помогите найти решение, чтобы на картинку выводилось эмодзи.

Comment: [embedded_color=True](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.text)?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно только убедится, что выбранный шрифт поддерживает эмодзи. Я проверял через фотошоп и те шрифты что показывают вместо смайла - [], [?],[X] не подходят.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

# Создаем изображение
image = Image.new("RGB", (550, 100), (0, 0, 0))
drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

# Шрифт с поддержкой эмодзи
font_size = 49
font_path = "C:/Windows/Fonts/seguisym.ttf"  
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, font_size)

# Текст с эмодзи
emoji_text = "\U0001F60A 05:02 i don't sleep! "

#Рисуем
drawer.text((10, 10), emoji_text, (255, 255, 255), font=font)

# Сохраняем изображение
image.save("out_image.png")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Font: emojione.otf
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рисоваться они будут точно так же, как выглядят в текстовом редакторе, а не цветными как в фотошопе и т.д: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так что если вы хотите помесить цветной смайлик поверх вашего изображение, то сперва вам нужно подготовить .png
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PIL import Image

# Открываем основное изображение
background_path = "output_image.png" 
background = Image.open(background_path)

# Открываем изображение, которое вы хотите поместить поверх основного
overlay_path = "Без имени-1.png"  
overlay = Image.open(overlay_path)

# Устанавливаем координаты для размещения изображения
position = (10, 10)  

# Накладываем изображение с учетом альфа-канала
background.paste(overlay, position, overlay)

# Сохраняем результат
background.save("output_overlay.jpg")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]